# XCode 3.2 supports iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode3.2, xcode3to4

My app was developed using Xcode 3.2 and now it's required to support iPhone 5 , actually it runs on iPhone 5 but the display is clipped showing some black space at the buttom and top,

The issue now is I want to support iPhone 5 full Screen in my application, so is it required to upgrade to the latest xcode version or it can be adjusted??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You really should be using Xcode 4.5 or later. Set your project's Base SDK to "latest" (6.1) and your Deployment Target to 4.3. Of course this will requires lots of code updates to deal with API changes and the iOS 6 changes to view controller rotations. You need to keep current to develop for iOS/OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an image of the name `Default-568h@2x.png` with proper resolution `(640x1136)` pixel in your root folder.